# how to change content SideDrawer after click on button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this lib for my project.

https://github.com/adamrocker/simple-side-drawer

I would like to change current layout of SideDrawer to another layout.

is it possible ?

[image]

there are many applications that use this approach. like :

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zalora.android&hl=en

[image]

[image]

is there an example ?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code provided in the github repository you've referenced. I found this :

```
mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);

mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);
findViewById(R.id.leftBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mNav.toggleLeftDrawer();
    }
});

mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_right_simple);
    findViewById(R.id.rightBtn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mNav.toggleRightDrawer();
    }
});
```

So maybe you cuold have a listner on your button in the leftBehindContent which will perform action like :

```
mNav.setRightBehindContentView(R.layout.new_layout)
```

new_layout.xml must be present in your android layout folder ;) !